# How to use Suggest right

Tags: word-usage

Who suggested you **to** do that?

Who suggested you do that?

I suggest you do go there tomorrow./ I suggest you to go there tomorrow.
He suggested I deal with the matter at hand discreetly./ He suggested me to deal with the matter at hand discreetly.

We don't use the preposition **to**, using sentences where we're talking about how someone suggests/suggested someone does/did something, right?

Comment: According to the LDOC here http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/suggest there're some ways like "suggest (that)" or "suggest doing something"

Comment: You can see this link, It is somehow related : http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/85576/verbs-taking-only-second-direct-object

Comment: Visit http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/suggest#suggest__6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We offer a suggestion of an action.

> I suggest that you eat lunch now, because the cafe will be very busy later.

To construct a suggestion first create an instruction:

> You eat lunch now

That's grammatical but sounds rather like an order. In many friendly circumstances we'd soften that:

> You could eat lunch now

This has now become more of a suggestion, we've made it clear that the other person is free to make their own decision. We can take that a step further and explicitly state that we are making a suggestion:

> I suggest that you eat lunch now

notice here that we have used **that**. Applying this to one of your examples

> I suggest that you go there tomorrow

The big difference from your formulation is that we do not say

> I suggest you to

We do not use **you to**. The person is not the object of **suggest**, we are not suggesting a person, we are suggesting an action.

It is common, especially when speaking to miss out the **that** so we get

> I suggest you eat lunch now
>
> I suggest you go there tomorrow

It may help to recognise the structure if you pretend that the **that** is actually there.