# Usage of the ANSWER and GIVE ANSWER

Tags: word-usage, verbs, word-difference, nouns

Can you please explain me the distinction between the words "answer" and "give answer" and feed back over the examples below?

> 1. Answer the question.
> 2. Give the answer.

Comment: Tip: you mean [explain _to_ me](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/81617/36187). Also, see [How to properly make a list](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4827/36187).

Answer (score 3):

Many words in English can function as both a noun and a verb. Answer is one of them. So you can say

> John answered the question (a verb)
>
> John gave an answer to the question (a noun)

These sentences have the same meaning.  Your examples also have the same meaning.

Comment: Thanks but what I meant is might be as a result of pull of mother tongue many people say

Comment: Thanks but are these expressions correct which some of the non native speakers use.    Can I give answer?  for.. Can I answer?    Or.  He gave answer  for... He answered.