# Is this grammatically correct - "I miss to swim"

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

I read [this](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/common-verbs/miss) article and here it is mentioned that "I miss to swim" is grammatically incorrect. However, I do not see any issue with it.

Could some language expert please clarify.

Comment: Please look up the verb miss. Hint: it works like love, hate, like with ing.

Comment: @Lambie I Google'ed but couldn't understand. I am not a native English user, so it would be better if you could explain the concept, if you know.

Comment: It would help us if we understood what you found when you searched and why that didn’t help you.

Comment: @ColleenV Could you recommend me some good English Grammar online resource, I have been reading - https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/ ....

Comment: See at EL&U: *[When should a verb be followed by a gerund instead of an infinitive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329)*

Comment: We have a list of [Resources for learning English](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english) that might help. Also “recommend me” isn’t felicitous, you would say “Could you recommend some good resources...” It is similar to “explain” https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/57947/9161

Comment: @ColleenV Bingo. I love you so much for pointing out that "recommend" mistake of mine. :) Since I am not a native English user so I do many such mistakes, I am still learning. I am trying and trying. I hope I will improve my English Grammar and some day I will be able to answer questions on this site, instead of just asking questions.

Comment: If you do know an answer, you should post it even if your English isn’t perfect. We will help.

Comment: @Lambie Not in every context -- "I love to swim" or "I hate to swim" are both idtiomatic but not "I miss to swim", so 'miss' isn't working exactly like either of those.

Comment: @Glen_b Read this - https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329/when-should-a-verb-be-followed-by-a-gerund-instead-of-an-infinitive .... "miss" verb should be followed by gerund, so I think that's why "I miss to swim" is wrong...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not very sure as to why it isn't grammatically correct, but it doesn't sound very natural to me. I would rather say **"I miss swimming"**. You see, English has a bunch of unwritten rules especially when it comes down to gerunds. "I miss to swim" isn't something we really say. why? like I said, there are things in the language that you'll only learn by **hearing** every day. I could come up with a very detailed explanation, but you'd still run into exceptions such as **"I love to swim vs I love swimming"** for instance. I would recommend that you look up **"List of verbs followed by gerunds in English"** and try memorizing them.

[Verbs followed by gerunds](http://www.englishpage.com/gerunds/gerund_list.htm)

Comment: Some work both ways, others do not. But your advice is sound.

Comment: Correct, that's why you should immerse yourself in the language as much as possible. YouTube is one of the best sources of information there is nowadays.